# How to get data from a caml results using caml

Tags: sharepoint, caml

The scene is:
  I've got items using caml on a list view(e.g. previewlist), and I'll have to query again from these items, is it possible using caml to query from SPListItemsCollection? as MSSQL we can do `select * from(select * from tablename)`, but how can we finished that in caml ?

And if that impossible, i'll have to search from those items first and then add the result to a splist or a spview, anybody knows how to do this? (yeah, two diff ideas).

Comment: Did you try the [CAML Query editor](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) ? With this tool you can create very complex queries, I think you can do with this tool what you want.

Comment: If you already have these items fetched, why do you insist on filtering them with CAML rather than iterating over the collection with conventional LINQ or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using [SourceQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.sourcequery%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property, retrieve original query and build new one using  operator to combine two queries?